# Deep learning for image classification (rotation and scaling specifications)

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How can we come with a Deep learning model that detects whether a given image contains a line or and ellipse, and if it contains an ellipse, what are the parameters of the ellipse (center point, axes, and rotation angle)?

Answer (score 0):

You can train a [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) to detect shapes. A lot of frameworks (e.g. tensorflow) provide existing models, which you can use for transfer learning to speed up the process. Probably there are already existing models for detecting basic shapes.

I would doubt that it makes sense to calculate shape properties via deep learning, like center point eg. If you know the type of the shape, why not using geometric functions to get those shape properties?